# Get top 5 on 2 distinct where clause

Tags: postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, union

On postgres I have data like:

```
id | device_model | device_type
1  | "samsung"    | 1
2  | "iphone 4"   | 1
3  | "samsung"    | 1
4  | "ipad"       | 0
5  | "ipad"       | 0
```

And I'm looking to get the top 5 of device_model per device_type.

for the moment I'm doing :

```
SELECT device_model, COUNT(*)
FROM devices
GROUP BY device_model  
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
limit 5;
```

But it doesn't render top5 for each device_type. What can I use to do this? Seems I need to do a UNION.

Can I do something like :

```
SELECT device_model, COUNT(*)
FROM devices
WHERE device_type = 1
GROUP BY device_model  
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 5 
UNION
SELECT device_model, COUNT(*)
FROM devices
WHERE device_type = 0
GROUP BY device_model  
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 5;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNION"
LINE 7: UNION ALL
        ^
Query failed
PostgreSQL said: syntax error at or near "UNION"
```

Comment: What order constitutes "top" ?

Comment: number of times device_model is present. In my case `"samsung" 2`, "iphone 4" for device_type 1, `"ipad" 2` for device_type 0.

Comment: `device_model` and `device_type` are independent and represent two grouping variables?

Comment: sorry @pietrop I'm not sure I understand your question. The final data looks like  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/35d9a52ec3ea78024abc48e80f1a1314

Comment: @BeniMio Your solution doesn't handle devices that have the same rank. Take a look at my answer. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right query:

```
WITH counts AS (
    SELECT device_model, device_type, COUNT(id) AS cnt, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY device_type ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC) AS model_rank
    FROM devices
    GROUP BY device_model, device_type
)
SELECT device_model, device_type, cnt, model_rank
FROM counts
WHERE model_rank <= 5
ORDER BY device_type, model_rank
```

It handles models that has the same rank, displaying more than 5 rows per device type just in case.

In order to test it, create a table and fill it with data:

```
CREATE TABLE devices (
    id serial,
    device_model text,
    device_type integer
);

INSERT INTO devices (device_model, device_type)
    VALUES
        ('samsung', 1),
        ('iphone4', 1),
        ('samsung', 1),
        ('iphone4', 1),
        ('samsung', 1),
        ('samsung', 1),
        ('samsung', 1),
        ('samsung', 1),
        ('ipad', 0),
        ('ipad', 0),
        ('ipad', 0),
        ('ipad', 0),
        ('ipad', 0),
        ('iphone6', 1),
        ('iphone3', 1),
        ('iphone3', 1),
        ('iphone3', 1),
        ('iphone2', 1),
        ('iphone1', 1),
        ('iphone1', 1),
        ('iphone1', 1),
        ('iphone1', 1),
        ('iphone1', 1),
        ('iphone1', 1),
        ('kindle', 0),
        ('kindle', 0),
        ('kindle', 0),
        ('kindle', 0)
;
```

The output of the initial query is the following:

```
 device_model | device_type | cnt | model_rank 
--------------+-------------+-----+------------
 ipad         |           0 |   5 |          1
 kindle       |           0 |   4 |          2
 iphone1      |           1 |   6 |          1
 samsung      |           1 |   6 |          1
 iphone3      |           1 |   3 |          3
 iphone4      |           1 |   2 |          4
 iphone6      |           1 |   1 |          5
 iphone2      |           1 |   1 |          5
(8 rows)
```

Feel free to ask questions about the logic behind this solution.

Comment: Wow @pietrop it's work. I will dig to documentation do understand properly `rank()`, `OVER` and `PARTITION`.

Comment: @BeniMio they are used to windowing over a subset of rows related to the currently evaluated row. `OVER` creates a window, `rank()` returns the ordering number for each rows of the subset and `PARTITION` behaves like `GROUP BY`. You can't use the default `GROUP BY` inside a window, so they invented `PARTITION`. Here `PARTITION` is used to apply `rank()` to each "partition" (or "group") of the window and the partitioning criteria is `device_type`. `ORDER BY` orders the subset of rows inside each partition, so you get the `rank()` of each row of the subset ordered by `COUNT(id) desc`.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I'm doing :

```
(SELECT device_type, device_model, COUNT(*)
FROM devices
WHERE device_type = 1
GROUP BY device_type, device_model  
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 5)
UNION 
(SELECT device_type, device_model, COUNT(*)
FROM devices
WHERE device_type = 0
GROUP BY device_type, device_model  
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

It's working but maybe it can be refactored or changed.

Comment: Why are you using `UNION`?

Comment: Because the two request are different. Didn't found a way to do it without